# Obtaining the aggregate sum of one value from multiple columns in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions

I have a table the equivalent of;

box, fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, no1, no2, no3

1, apple, banana, orange, 12, 23, 7

2, pear, apple, banana, 5, 15, 11

...

I want to run a query which will aggregate the total number of apples, oranges and bananas. It should result in (for boxes 1 and 2):

fruit, no

apples, 27

bananas, 34

oranges, 7

pears, 5

I obviously can't do a simple sum() and group by because I want to group by the fruit as it appears in any *column*, not just a single one.

Also, in the real life version, there are more than 100 different types of 'fruit' so doing a case...when selection for each one isn't really viable.

Answer (score 0):

Call off the dogs, I've got it;

select
fruit,
sum(number),
from
(
select
fruit1 as fruit,
sum(no1) as number,
from fruit_table
group by fruit1
union
select
fruit2 as fruit,
sum(no2) as number,
from fruit_table
group by fruit2
union
select
fruit3 as fruit,
sum(no3) as number,
from fruit_table
group by fruit3
union
select
)
Group by fruit

Create a union of all the different tables then aggregate from that unionC